# Spark Streaming - DStream does not have distinct()

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to count the distinct value of some type of IDs represented as an RDD.

In the non-streaming case, it's fairly straightforward. Say `IDs` is an RDD of IDs read from a flat file.

```
    print ("number of unique IDs %d" %  (IDs.distinct().count()))
```

But I can't seem to do the same thing in the streaming case. Say we have `streamIDs` be a `DStream` of IDs read from the network.

```
    print ("number of unique IDs from stream %d" %  (streamIDs.distinct().count()))
```

Gives me this error

```
AttributeError: 'TransformedDStream' object has no attribute 'distinct'
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I printout the number of distinct IDs that showed up during this batch?

Answer (score 9):

With RDDs you have a single result, but with DStreams you have a series of results with a result per micro batch. So you cannot print the number of unique ids once, but instead you have to register an action to print the unique ids for each micro batch, which is a RDD on which you can use distinct:

```
streamIDs.foreachRDD(rdd => println(rdd.distinct().count()))
```

Remember you can use `window` to create a transformed dstream with bigger batches:

```
streamIDs.window(Duration(1000)).foreachRDD(rdd => println(rdd.distinct().count()))
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using:

```
yourDStream.transform(r => r.distinct())
```