# What is the distinct() equivalent in pyspark dstream?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, bigdata, spark-streaming, rdd

I use `pyspark` & I have a `dstream` like below,

```
mystream = dstream.map(lambda y: (y[0], y[1])).distict().groupByKey()
mystream.pprint()
```

But unfortunately, it says `AttributeError: 'TransformedDStream' object has no attribute 'distict'`. Why `distict()`supports in rdd based operation but not in dstream? What is the `distict()` equivalent in dstream?

Comment: Did you really write `distict`? Not `distinct` (mind the n)? Additionally, this seems to have been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573962/spark-streaming-dstream-does-not-have-distinct).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Streaming - DStream does not have distinct()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573962/spark-streaming-dstream-does-not-have-distinct)

Comment: Thanks  for the link Oliver W!! I use Python. The link you have shared using Scala. I am not familiar with Scala syntax.

Comment: By the way I have tried with 'distinct'.. its a typo when I posted it. thanks.